# How to use Apache Pulsar for ordered batch processing

Tags: apache-pulsar

Consider the following example:

- There are tens of thousands of shops around the world where internal processes should be recorded
- For each shop location the order of internal process tasks must be preserved
- There is no global list of shops. Process tasks may fly in from one location, without previous knowledge about that location
- Recording the process tasks is critical, no task must be missed (failover)

My understanding is that in order to preserve the order of processes within each location, I need to create a topic for each store location like this:

persistent://public/default/store-san-francisco

And for each topic I need to create an exclusive consumer with failovers.

The problem is that since I do not know the locations in advance, what is the best way to create a consumer ad-hoc for each unknown location?

Answer (score 2):

New to Pulsar, but my understanding is that the Broker will automatically create a topic if one doesn't exist. Also, since you can list topics from the console admin utility, I would assume you can also do that programmatically, keep a running list of topics/consumers, and create a new one if a new topic shows up.

Answer (score 1):

You can now use [Key shared subscriptions](https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/en/2.3.2/concepts-messaging/#key_shared) which will preserve the order for a given key. For your use case you can produce and consume to a single `store` topic and use the store name (eg. `store-san-francisco`) as key. On the consuming side, you can read the concerned store name in the message metadata.